# Echo a string variable1 from a particular variable2 index to the end

Tags: batch-file, variables, indexing

I currently have to read a txt file, with Batch. The txt file contains several lines like those :

> ```
> tag1 filepath1
> tag2 filepath2
> tag3 filepath3
> ...
> ```

The goal is to save filepath1, for example, into a variable, so that i can use it later.

At the moment, I manage to read the line containing tag1, et I can count the number of characters in the string "tag1 ".

I have the following variables :

- mytag containing the string "tag1 "
- myvariable containing the string "tag1 filepath1"
- myindex containing the length of variable mytag (so 5).

Now, I need to display only filepath1.
I usually use the following syntax to display a variable from a certain index, for example 5 :

```
echo %myvariable:~5%
```

Except that in this case, the index is a variable.

I tried the following :

```
echo %myvariable:~myindex%
```

Needless to say, it doesn't work...

Does someone know how i could isolate filepath 1 ?

Comment: `@Call Echo(%%myvariable:~%myindex%%%` or use delayed expansion and `Echo(!myvariable:~%myindex%!`
This assumes of course that your index is correct for the data your attempting to extract.

Comment: I used the second solution. Works like a charm, thanks !

Comment: How can i classify your answer as the good one ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `for /f` loop to get the desired string.

Here are two methods. The first one processes each line. Your variable ("filepathX") is `%%b`

The second one assumes you want the filepath for a given tag and sets it to a variable for future use.

```
@echo off
setlocal 
echo ---- all lines ----
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (test.txt) do (
  echo Tag is %%a, Data is %%b.
)
echo ---- a specified line ----
set "mytag=tag2"
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('findstr /bi "%mytag%\>" test.txt') do set "filepath=%%b"
echo Data for %mytag% is %filepath%.
```

See `for /?` and `findstr /?` for more information.

Comment: Rather than resetting a variable for each specified line, the OP could just turn the second option into a macro and supply the target using substitution.

`Set "Get.Tag=For /F "tokens=1,* Delims= " %%G in (' Findstr.exe /BLIC:"tag# " "test.txt"')Do Set "%%G=%%H""` Will return tag 3 in the variable  'tag3' when expanded %Get.Tag:#=3%

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @T3RR0R, @Calculuswhiz and @Stephan.

The two answers work.
I have a preference for @T3RR0R 's answer, since it is one short ligne of calcul :

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set mypath=!myvariable:~%myindex%!
```

I can use this code inside a function and return the wanted value.

Comment: If there is always just one space between the tag and the data: `set "mypath=%myvariable:* =%"` removes everything from the start, up to (including) the first space. Would save you the time-consuming length calculation.